# Characterization of the Riemann curvature tensor

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M^n,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, $a\in M$ be a fixed point. It it well known that there exists a coordinate system near $a$ (e.g. the normal one) such that 
$$g_{ij}(x)=\delta_{ij}+O(|x|^2).$$

Furthermore it is also well known that there exists a coordinate system near $a$ such that the next terms in the decomposition of $g_{ij}(x)$ into the Taylor series contain only components of the Riemann curvature tensor $R_{ijkl}$.

**Question 1.** How does the precise formula look like? A reference would be helpful.

**Question 2.** Is there a characterization of $R_{ijkl}$ along these lines? Namely is there a statement saying (roughly) that $R_{ijkl}$ is the only tensor constructed from the second derivatives of $g_{ij}$ which satisfies the formula answering Question 1?

Comment: Does this answer your question: http://mathoverflow.net/a/185555/613

Comment: Thanks, Deane! That note contains answers to both my questions.